What are examples of (non-thermal) states with non-singular $P$ function?
We know that the $P$ function of (displaced) thermal states is smooth and positive. Indeed, as shown e.g. here, a thermal state $\rho_{\rm th}(x)\equiv (1-x)x^{a^\dagger a}$, $x\equiv e^{-\beta}$, has $P$ function
$$P_x(\nu) = \frac{1-x}{\pi x} \exp\left(-\frac{1-x}{x} |\nu|^2\right).$$
Displaced thermal states of course give essentially the same expression.
In the limit $x\to0$ this becomes $\delta^2(\nu)$, consistently with the thermal state approaching the vacuum state $|0\rangle$.
Other typical examples of states with known $P$ function are Fock states: the $P$ function of the Fock state $|n\rangle$ is a $2n$-th derivative of $\delta^2(\nu)$ (and is thus highly singular).
What are other "simple" examples of states that have a non-singular $P$-function?
Of course, any mixture of (displaced) thermal states would foot the bill, but I'm looking for other nontrivial examples.
For example, any example involving a pure state would be nice.
Ideally, cases where the $P$ function can be computed analytically (or at least shown analytically to be regular).

My impression is that W Schleich's book is a prime source of this type of thing...

@CosmasZachos I don't see any such example in the book. At least not in chapter 12 where they discuss $P$ function and other distributions. The only additional example they consider that I haven't mentioned are squeezed states, which however also have singular $P$ function (expression in page 343)

Hudson's theorem established that all pure states with positive Wigner functions are Gaussian states (i.e., they are squeezed and/or displaced vacuum states, perhaps multimode versions). Since the Wigner function is a convolution of the P function, the negativity of the Wigner function implies the negativity of the P function, so the only possible states with positive P functions are those with positive Wigner functions.
Thus, if you really want pure states with positive P functions, the only possibilities are squeezed coherent states. Then you simply show that squeezing always makes a state have a negative P function (any squeezed state has negative P somewhere, displacements only move that around in phase space) and you discover that the only pure states with positive P distributions are coherent states, there are no others.

Weirdly enough, this feels like it's answering a different question than the one I'm asking here... which was precisely the question I almost asked instead of this one: "what are examples of pure states with non-negative $P$ function?". Still, it's great info also relevant here, and passing through Hudson's is a nice idea, thanks! There's no pure states with smooth non-negative $P$. So then the question becomes: what are examples (if any exist) of pure states with smooth $P$ function of any kind?

@glS and if, by "smooth," you mean non-singular, then "By a theorem of Schwartz, distributions that are more singular than the Dirac delta function are always negative somewhere". So if you want non-singular, you need positive, which means you need a coherent state if restricted to pure states

of that I'm aware, but here the question is in the other direction: are there non-singular $P$ functions corresponding to pure states (or for that matter, non-singular $P$ functions other than displaced thermal states, which is the only case that I always see discussed in this context)? Yes I was using "smooth" as equivalent to "non-singular".. I assumed non-singular (ie properly defined functions, not distributions) $P$ functions would be smooth (ie $C^\infty$). In fairness, I'm not sure that's the case. But that's probably matter for another post

@glS maybe we are misunderstanding each other. Non-singular P functions must be positive, positive P functions for pure states must be coherent, that's it! Then the question for mixed states seems more complicated, for example because there are non-Gaussian mixed states with positive Wigner functions. I would naively suggest taking any positive, normalizeable function, so I could suggest $P(\alpha)\propto\exp(-|\alpha|^4)$, which is not a thermal state and looks smooth, but I'm not sure whether it breaks an uncertainty principle or something else

ok I missed the last remark in your comment above. But how do you get that "if you want non-singular, you need positive"? Schwartz's result says that more singular than a delta implies negative (and positive I presume) somewhere (ie it excludes $P\ge0$ and $P\le 0$); but this says nothing about the other direction. Clearly ($P\not\ge0$ and $P\not\le0$) doesn't imply $P$ is a singular distribution. It thus could still be the case that there's pure $\rho$ with smooth $P\not\ge0$, no?

@glS sorry you are correct. If you want to guarantee non singular, you need positive, but agreed it doesn't work the other way around. (Yes P must always be positive somewhere to be trace 1.) So is Schwartz an if and only iff? Probably not, given the language in the linked quote. I like your question. So then, if you take a sinc function for the P distribution, does anything stop you from calling it a state?

in further support your arguments for the case of positive non-singular $P$ function: I later found this 1985 paper by Mark Hiller titled "Classical pure states are coherent states" which proves pretty much the same exact thing

@glS good find, it agrees with me, but it doesn't answer your question. They assume that the smooth part of the state is positive, while you might find a smooth pure state that is negative somewhere. And then they also consider only convex combinations of delta functions, which we know to be convex combinations of coherent states, so they essentially found that the only convex combination of coherent states that is pure is the one with only one coherent state. Your question might consider delta functions to be smooth enough
